# Django Project : 'dict' object has no attribute 'code'

Tags: python, django

I retrieved a list of products via an API, then I use django-shopping-cart to generate my cart
But I have an error 'dict' object has no attribute 'code'.

the error is at this line : if product.code == code ,while there is indeed the code attribute in the dict

```
def cart_add(request,code):
url='http://myapi/Product/GetProducts'
x=requests.get(url)
content=x.json()
all_products=content['products']
for product in all_products :
    if product.code == code :
        cart=Cart(request)
        cart.add(product = product.code)
return render(request,'shop/deatil.html')
```

At the API level, the dictionary specification is of the form:

```
dict = {
     "products": [
     {
       "code": "4mlk2",
       "designation": "kaka"
     },
     {
       "code": "455ml",
       "designation": "koko"
     },
     ....
    ]
   }
```

Comment: You access dict values using `dict[key]` in your example it will be: product["code"]. Read: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic issue I'm also having when switching over eg from Javascript :-)
There is no dot notation in python to access dicts. There are basically 2 way to access a dict in python:

`product["code"]`

or

`product.get("code")`

The latter has the advantage that you can pass in a default value in case the key "code" is not available:

`product.get("code", "123421")`